# use format with tex fraction expression in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I use matplotlib. I need to get xlabels like: [1/8,2/8,3/8,4/8..14/8]. I want to make it in a loop.  Therefore, for better view I use TEX in Python. For rendering the fraction expression in the loop I use .format method. But it doesn't work properly. There is some conflict between using of {} in TEX and .format method. I tried to use double {} but it as well doesn't work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xax = ax.xaxis  # get x axis

labels = ['0']
for i in range(0, 14):
    labels.append(r'$\frac{}{8}$'.format(i)) # when trying to insert i an error occurs

xax.set_ticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The `{8}` into `.format()` is causing issues. You could leave it empty and pass the `8` as a second parameter to `format()`. such as: `'$\frac{}{}$'.format(i, 8)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It produces an error `ValueError: 
\frac18
     ^
Expected \frac{num}{den}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the curled brackets (`{`) with another curled bracket.

```
r'$\frac{{{}}}{{8}}$'.format(i)
```

Here the inner most bracket pair in `{{{}}}` is used for formatting. The escape pair `{{` is replaced by a single bracket during formatting. Hence `r'$\frac{{{}}}{{8}}$'.format(1)` will result in `r'$\frac{1}{8}$'`, which is then a valid MathText string.

Comment: Yeah! It works! But can you explain. It means that {{8}} it's like one pair of {} for TEX to make it fraction, second pair for .format, but what about {{{}}}?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

instead of raw string, you can also use the f-string,
both of the following can get \frac{a}{b} for any input a, b,

```
f"$\frac{{{a}}}{{{b}}}$"

f"$\\frac{{{a}}}{{{b}}}$"
```